# collapse elements for loaded xml in webbrowser control using c# to a certain depth/level

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I am using the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser to display XML. If i load the XML into the Control by default the elements are completely expanded.
The user can collapse them manually to the depth/level that he wants.

Is it possible to collapse the elements to a certain depth/level with C# code. Let's say the XML elements are expanded to a depth of 2 or 3 and all the below elements are collapsed?

The thread that I tried is the below one, but it did not solve my problem completely.

[collapse all elements for loaded xml in webbrowser control using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379665/collapse-all-elements-for-loaded-xml-in-webbrowser-control-using-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that if you check how the generated structure looks - the the depth of the collapse `<a>` tag acts as the indicator of how deep in the tree you are. So you can just use JavaScript to match a certain level of links and collapse them. You can do that either manually (traversing the document and recursively entering the sub-elements while keeping a variable that will track the current depth - for the basics check [this article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom) ) or via some CSS-style element matching.

Comment: thanks for the response and the article link you ve placed. Good to know that the depth can be measured. I will study the XML javascript basics to build the right statement.